# GeoPandas Spatial Join with random samples

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join, spatial-statistics

I have a geopandas DataFrame with `Polygon` geometry and another one with `POINT` geometry. I'd like to do a spatial join between them and randomly select a set of `points` that are within certain distance or close to the polygon.

Here's some sample data:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c3c5863af9fe855491e4ef71f21a64b

Criteria:

Select `n` randomly sampled points from top `m` nearest points between `gpd2.geometry` (Point) to each `gpd1.geometry` (Polygon).

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

gpd_merged = gpd.sjoin(
                       gpd1, # polygon geometry
                       gpd2, # point geometry (randomly sample and join) 
                       how = 'left',
                       distance_col = "distances"
                      )
```

Comment: Can you also provide those points as you did with [polygons](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c3c5863af9fe855491e4ef71f21a64b) ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The following will randomly sample n points within a specified distance of each poly.

It uses [`gpd.sjoin_nearest`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html) to assign all points to the closest polygon within a certain distance, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)  and [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) to randomly select the desired number of points per polygon.

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf_points = gpd.read_file(points)
gdf_poly = gpd.read_file(polys)

max_distance = 0.1
n_points = 3

gdf_randomsample = gpd.sjoin_nearest(
    gdf_points,       # point geometry
    gdf_poly,         # polygon geometry
    how='inner',      # drop points outside max_distance
    max_distance=max_distance
).groupby("id_right").sample(n=n_points)
```

Here's an example with your polygons (the buffer represents the specified max distance):

[image]

But note that the little polygon "ID" 2 gets no points assigned to it as all points are closer to the other polygons.

[image]